# Is there a Stack Exchange website for 'help me understand this code' questions?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I was commenting on a post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443220/can-someone-please-try-to-explain-this-code?noredirect=1#comment41529474_26443220), and I checked the help menu on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting a comment saying: maybe put it on Code Review.

Another person told me that it wasn't suited for Code Review. They are probably right, but now what do I do, is there another Stack Exchange website for this? Should I answer the question on Stack Overflow or where else can I direct them to?

Comment: SO is best suited, but it must be specific enough.

Comment: I'm torn on this.  Stack Overflow *might* be suited for it, but I have strong reservations about the quality or usefulness of any question that pertains to this subject.  Code Review is meant for working code and tips on how to improve it, so there's **no** way that a question about "help me understand this code" would be on topic there.

Comment: If there's one particular line (or maybe up to a function) that's confusing, the question is probably narrow enough to post here.  Such questions may be too localized, but that's not a close reason anymore, and if the code is from a widely-used library or example application they may help others with a similar question.  Also, some of these questions are actually asking "Explain language feature X to me" and can be closed as duplicates of canonical questions about those features, if they exist.

Comment: Area 51 proposal: [Code understanding](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65174/code-understanding)

Comment: I think you should ask *"Is there a Stack Exchange website"* questions in [Meta stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Questions like this have a high risk of getting too broad or to specific (i.e. not helping anyone) or both. This means they aren't suited for any Stack Exchange website. We should not forget that there are questions which don't belong to the Stack Exchange website, sometimes we can't refer to another site.

However, I don't believe we should search for these questions and all vote for close and deletion. While they have a high risk, some of them can be very usefull for anyone else and stay very specific. An example is [Why does this JavaScript work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090434/why-does-this-javascript-work/13090497)

In this case, the operator is very broad and does not include just one single thing (like the previous question).

Comment: A huge portion of questions on stackoverflow are specific.

Comment: The title of your example question is awful. It could be used for like 50% of the total javascript questions out there. It ought to be changed to something that can be search for (otherwise the question is still pretty useless).

Answer (score 3):

There is no one single answer for this because it all depends on the circumstance. But having said that, usually the golden rule of asking questions applies well to this situation: the questioner should strive to put in as much effort into asking their question as they'd like a volunteer to expend in answering it. There's no excuse for dumping in a mass of code and asking that it be explained, but there should be no problem for someone posting a reasonable amount of code, explaining their thoughts on it and the results of their efforts to understand and use it, and then ask pointed and specific questions regarding specific points of misunderstanding. Those types of questions should be allowed as they can be quite helpful for future visitors.